# W2UI with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, w2ui

I have following code:

```
                if(w2ui.hasOwnProperty('layout')){
                    w2ui['layout'].destroy();
                }
                if(w2ui.hasOwnProperty('grid')){
                    w2ui['grid'].destroy();
                }

                $(function () {
                    $('#grid').w2grid({
                        name: 'grid',
                        show: {
                            footer: true
                        },
                        columns: [
                            { field: 'fname', caption: 'Date Time', size: '200px',
                                render: function (record, index, column_index) {
                                    var html = '<div>'+ record.fname + ' ' + record.lname + '</div>';
                                    return html;
                                }
                            },
                            { field: 'email', caption: 'Subsystem', size: '100%' },
                            { field: 'profit',caption: 'ACCES Message Type', size: '120px', render: 'money' }
                        ],
                        records: '{{model.messages}}'
                        //[
//                                { recid: 1, fname: 'John', lname: 'Doe', email: 'john@gmail.com', profit: 2500},
//                                { recid: 2, fname: 'Stuart', lname: 'Motzart', email: 'stuart@gmail.com', profit: 1004},
//                                { recid: 3, fname: 'Jin', lname: 'Franson', email: 'jin@gmail.com', profit: 473},
//                                { recid: 4, fname: 'Susan', lname: 'Ottie', email: 'susan@gmail.com', profit: 304},
//                                { recid: 5, fname: 'Kelly', lname: 'Silver', email: 'kelly@gmail.com', profit: 9300},
                        //]
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Question is, how can I to deliver a data from Angular's controller.

```
records: '{{model.messages}}'
```

It is a classic of policy code, project ends in one month...

Comment: Where is your script tag located?

Comment: <head> <body> ? Where is you app (`ng-app`) initialized?

Comment: One sure thing is that ng-app is not in the same html file in which is <script> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose a method from your controller:

```
window.getErrMessages = function () {
    return $scope.messages;
};
```

I don't like to expose things like this but I don't see any other solution in your case.